# Power consumption of an inverter

Tags: inverter, solar-energy, power-consumption

I want to calculate the consumption of a PV inverter connected to a 50 kW PV plant. In the datasheet of the inverter it is written that the consumption of the inverter is: < 0.24% of Pac,r. I really don't know what is Pac,r. I found Pacr that is 55 kW but I don't think that an inverter has a consumption of 13200 W. Is it possible? I allegate the screenshot of the part of the datasheet where it is written. It is in Italian unfortunately, but probably someone that has a experience with inverters can help me anyway. Do you know what is the consumption of this inverter?

[image]

Comment: Are you confusing 55kW*0.24 with 55kW*0.24% by any chance? The latter would be 132W auxiliary consumption, not 13200W. (Note this is additional to the efficiency)

Answer (score 1):

From the efficiency rating of 98% you can calculate how much power it is consuming:
$$Eff=\frac{Pout}{Pin}$$

[image]

So if you have \$100W\$ going to your **load**, then you'll have
$$\frac{Pout}{Eff}=Pin \\$$ $$-$$ $$  \frac{100W}{0.98}=102W$$

And then
\$102W-100W=2W\$ consumed in the inverter.

Comment: You are right... I come from 13 hours of study, I'm giving the numbers ahahahha! Thank you very much!

Comment: @SamueleBenitoDiGioia Similarly, for 50 kW => 1 kW loss. Don't forget that that's the *maximum* efficiency. You should not rely on it, so 95~96% is more likely, and it may (or may not) drop even further with very light loads.